# gcloud ml-engine local prediction not working with iris example Could not parse example input

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud

I tried to extend a TensorFlow 1.4 [iris example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py) by using this code to save a model:

```
 feature_spec = {"sepal_length": tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], default_value=0.0),
              "sepal_width": tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], default_value=0.0),
              "petal_length": tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], default_value=0.0),
              "petal_width": tf.FixedLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], default_value=0.0)}
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="tmp/iris_model", serving_input_receiver_fn=export_input_fn)
```

And by using a text-file (iris.txt):

```
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5
```

Then doing local predictions like this:

```
MODEL_DIR=tmp/iris_model/1516913526
gcloud ml-engine local predict \
--model-dir $MODEL_DIR \
--text-instances ./iris.txt
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) 2018-01-25 22:12:00.675756: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
>   WARNING:root:MetaGraph has multiple signatures 3. Support for multiple signatures is limited. By default we select named signatures.
>   2018-01-25 22:12:00.818033: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: Could not parse example input, value: '5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5'
>   ERROR:root:Exception during running the graph: Could not parse example input, value: '5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5'
>        [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=4, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], dense_shapes=[[1 ], [1 ], [1 ], [1 ]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape)]]
>
> Caused by op u'ParseExample/ParseExample', defined at:
>     File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 111, in 
>     File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 106, in main
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 991, in local_predict
>       client = SessionClient(*load_model(model_dir, tags, signature_name))
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 410, in load_model
>       meta_graph = loader.load(session, tags=list(tags), export_dir=model_path)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 216, in load
>       saver = tf_saver.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def_to_load, **saver_kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1810, in import_meta_graph
>       **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 660, in import_scoped_meta_graph
>       producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 313, in import_graph_def
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Could not parse example input, value: '5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5'
>        [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=4, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], dense_shapes=[[1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py), [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py), [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py), [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py)], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape)]]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 111, in 
>       main()
>     File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 106, in main
>       instances=instances)
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 993, in local_predict
>       _, predictions = model.predict(instances)
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 375, in predict
>       predicted_outputs = self._client.predict(preprocessed, stats)
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 530, in predict
>       "Exception during running the graph: " + str(e))
>   prediction_lib.PredictionError: Failed to run the provided model: Exception during running the graph: Could not parse example input, value: '5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5'
>        [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=4, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], dense_shapes=[[ 1], [ 1], [ 1], [ 1]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape)]]
>
> Caused by op u'ParseExample/ParseExample', defined at:
>     File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 111, in 
>     File "lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/ml_engine/local_predict.py", line 106, in main
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 991, in local_predict
>       client = SessionClient(*load_model(model_dir, tags, signature_name))
>     File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/cloud_ml_engine_sdk/prediction/prediction_lib.py", line 410, in load_model
>       meta_graph = loader.load(session, tags=list(tags), export_dir=model_path)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 216, in load
>       saver = tf_saver.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def_to_load, **saver_kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1810, in import_meta_graph
>       **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 660, in import_scoped_meta_graph
>       producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 313, in import_graph_def
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Could not parse example input, value: '5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5'
>        [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=4, Nsparse=0, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], dense_shapes=[[1 ], [1 ], [1 ], [1 ]], sparse_types=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape, ParseExample/Reshape)]]
>    (Error code: 2)

What am I missing?

Comment: For the command, it looks like you're putting `--text-instances` on a different line than `./iris.txt`. In your prediction file, you may need to end your prediction data with a newline.

Comment: I think the \ fixes that and to me the prediction reads the numbers correctly  as it looks from the error message. (tested also removing \ and adding newline no difference,

Comment: Did you actually get it to work?